# Raspberry Pi on Network with ethernet but not connecting to internet

Tags: networking, internet, chromium, dns

I've had Pi-Hole on my pi to some success but after a while of inaction my pi cannot connect to the internet now. Unsure what will help, as I've tried what I thought were all the obvious things.

I'm on the network, arp-scan shows the other devices, I can ping them. I cannot use chromium out though, nor can I `ping 8.8.8.8`. My router has IP address `192.168.1.2` and modem `192.168.1.1`.

`cat /etc/resolv.conf` shows the following:

`nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver fe80::1%eth0
nameserver fe80::1%wlan0`

`ip route show` gives this:

`default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  metric 202 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.24  metric 202`

Chromium had been saying DNS or proxy or firewall may be the issue. It has since dropped the DNS complaint but I am still no better off.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: can you ping `www.google.com` successfully?

Comment: Can you show the output from `ifconfig` please? It's unusual these days to have a modem and router, which is sitting the DHCP and DNS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer appears to be to update bind with
`sudo apt-get install bind`
to fix `/etc/resolv.conf` allowing dhclient to complete at boot.

See this post [on the error dhclient was giving](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1057298): `irs_resconf_load failed: 59`.